# How to capture screenshot on failure scenario and attach it to report in testcafe?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, report, screenshot, testcafe

I'm using an HTML reporter in testcafe. Is it possible to capture a screenshot on the failure scenario and add that screenshot to report?

I'm able to capture a screenshot of failure scenarios. How to add it to an HTML report?

Does testcafe supports 'Extent' reports and 'beautify' reports?

Comment: [testcafe-reporter-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/testcafe-reporter-html) is a third party plugin and if you have a question about it. I recommend you open [an issue](https://github.com/picuscreative/testcafe-reporter-html/issues/new) on the github page of this reporter.

As for the 'Extent' and 'beautify' reports, I cannot find information about [testcafe's github page](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe#plugins).